# how to make custom authentication (login, remember me and registration) in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web

How can i make secure custom authentication system in mvc4. Things i have to add in

1. Check how many times a user entered wrong password.
2. Custom remember me ( for 5 days after that user have to login).
3. If remember me is checked in Computer by one user and same user changed password in other PC or laptop then, user in Computer automatically logged out ( When same user is logged in from different PC).

I have to make it in **mvc4 only**.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/how-to-configure-custom-membership-and-role-provider-using-asp-net-mvc4/

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC comes with a membership & role provider. They offer a lot of functionality that you are looking for.

You can create your own custom membership/role provider by simply inheriting from these providers and add your own logic.

Introduction membership provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx

Also take a look at: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7